# Is there a way to having different plots within a strategy be plotted in different panes?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

I'm using a couple of different MAs and oscillators in an indicator I'm working on and they're not playing nicely in the same pane. For example, when I try to configure something as a histogram, it plots onto the main chart pane which causes the columns to be enormous. If I move the histogram to another pane, it moves the histogram together with every other plot as well. The goal is to have some plot drawings to remain on 1 pane and others to be on another. Is this possible to do in PineScript?

Comment: No, that's not possible. You can make two versions of the script, the first version will display some plots in one panel, and the second one will display other plots in another panel.